# How to access dynamically added DataGridView inside a TabPage and get values?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have made a program that can import an excel file and insert all the sheets in a dynamically added tabpage with a dynamically added datagridview.

I want to insert the values of the KPI column depending on the tab selected on my combobox and everytime you change the tabpage, the combobox changes too. [image]

Here are my codes:

### **ReadExcel Method**

```
  public static void ReadExcel(ComboBox cboSheet, TabControl tabCon)
    {
       try
       {
           OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
           openFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files| *.xls; *xlsx";
           openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(openFileDialog.FileName))
           {
               OleDbcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + openFileDialog.FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'");
               OleDbcon.Open();

               DataTable dt = OleDbcon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
               OleDbcon.Close();

               cboSheet.Items.Clear();

               int width = 1330;
               int height = 565;
               //1338, 590

               for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
               {
                    if (!dt.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString().Contains("FilterDatabase") && !dt.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString().EndsWith("$'"))
                    {
                       String sheetName = dt.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                       sheetName = sheetName.Substring(0, sheetName.Length - 1);
                        //cboSheet.Items.Add(sheetName);

                        TabPage tp = new TabPage(sheetName);

                        DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
                        tp.Controls.Add(dataGridView);
                        tabCon.Controls.Add(tp);
                        CreateDataGrid(dataGridView, sheetName);
                        dataGridView.Size = new Size(width, height);
                        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();

                        //KPI Column
                    }
               }
           }
       }

       catch (Exception e)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());

       }

    }
```

---

### **CreateDataGrid Method**

```
  public static void CreateDataGrid(DataGridView dataGridView1, string TabName)
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter oleAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + TabName + "$]", ExcelMethods.OleDbcon);


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        oleAdapt.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Comment: You should clarify how the “KPI” column values are generated. I assume it is not part of the database and you add this column AFTER the database has been loaded into the grid. In addition, it is not clear how the “KPI” column values may change depending on which tab page is selected or which item is selected in the combo box. Can you clarify how the “KPI” column relates to the tab pages and how these “KPI” column values are generated? Are the “KPI” values static or do they change if the user changes the data?

Comment: KPI column values comes from the Excel File I imported. All the tabs are generated once I import it. The tab pages are the sheets in an excel file which are auto-generated along with the datagridview. The problem I'm experiencing now is calling the values from the datagridview and inputting the KPI column values to the combobox since they are auto-generated. Depending on the tab page selected (excel sheet), the values on the combobox would dynamically change too.

Comment: Currently from the posted picture, the “KPI” combo box is NOT contained in the `TabControl`. If the combo box WAS contained inside each individual tab page, then you could set the data source once for each combo box and forget it. However, since the combo box appears outside the `TabControl` and you want the combo box values to match the currently selected tab page…then it appears you will need to catch the `TabControls` `SelectedIndexChanged` event to update the combo box.

Comment: You could create a “global” list of strings from the KPI values of the selected tab page (non-duplicated), and then use this global list as a data source for the KPI combo box. When the user selects a different tab page, you can update the global list with the new values. There is also the option to save the different “KPI” strings to avoid re-reading from the data table.

Comment: Would it be better if just put all controls (`Combo Box` and `Checkbox` outside the `TabControl` inside each individual tab? The problem I'm facing with this one is calling the values to be put the KPI Column values to the `Combo Box` inside the tabcontrol...

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by… _calling the values to be put the KPI Column values to the Combo Box inside the tabcontrol_  … getting the values for the combo box should be relatively simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a simple win form program that demonstrates what I described in my comments. The form contains an empty `ComboBox` named `cb_KPI`. In addition it contains an empty `TabControl` named `tabControl1`.

A global variable is created `AllDataTables`. `AlldataTables` is a `DataSet` such that each `DataTable` in the `DataSet` is an existing worksheet from the user selected Excel workbook. This is used to hold the `DataTable` for each `TabPage`… i.e. `AllDataTables.Tables[0]` is the `DataTable` for `tabControl1.TabPages[0]`.

When the form is loaded, `AllDataTables` is filled with the user selected workbook’s worksheets… then, a loop through all the tables adds a new `TabPage` to the `tabControl1` for each table. Finally, the `cb_KPI` combo box is updated to contain the values for the currently selected `TabPage`.

```
DataSet AllDataTables;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  AllDataTables = GetDSFromExcel();
  foreach (DataTable dt in AllDataTables.Tables) {
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(GetTabPageWithGrid(dt));
  }
  cb_KPI.DataSource = SetKPI_ValuesForComboBox(AllDataTables.Tables[tabControl1.SelectedIndex]);
}
```

The `GetDSFromExcel` method returns a `DataSet` from a user selected Excel file where each `DataTable` in the `DataSet` is a worksheet from the user selected Excel file.

```
private DataSet GetDSFromExcel() {
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  try {
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog {
      Filter = "Excel Files| *.xls; *xlsx"
    };
    openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(openFileDialog.FileName)) {
      using (OleDbConnection OleDbcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + openFileDialog.FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'")) {
        OleDbcon.Open();
        DataTable WorkbookSheetInfo = OleDbcon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        String sheetName;
        DataTable dt;
        OleDbDataAdapter oleAdapt;
        for (int i = 0; i < WorkbookSheetInfo.Rows.Count; i++) {
          if ((WorkbookSheetInfo.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString().EndsWith("$'")) ||
              (WorkbookSheetInfo.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString().EndsWith("$"))) {
            sheetName = WorkbookSheetInfo.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString();
            dt = new DataTable(sheetName.Replace("'", "").Replace("$", ""));
            oleAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + sheetName + "]", OleDbcon);
            oleAdapt.Fill(dt);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    MessageBox.Show("ReadExcelIntoDS_Error" + e.ToString());
  }
  return ds;
}
```

The `GetTabPageWithGrid` method is given a `DataTable` and returns a single `TabPage` with a `DataGridView` such that the `DataGridView`’s `DataSource` will be the given `DataTable`

```
private TabPage GetTabPageWithGrid(DataTable dt) {
  TabPage tp = new TabPage(dt.TableName.Replace("'", "").Replace("$", ""));
  tp.Controls.Add(GetDGV(dt));
  return tp;
}

private DataGridView GetDGV(DataTable dt) {
  return new DataGridView {
    Size = new Size(1000, 400),
    Name = "datagridView" + dt.TableName,
    DataSource = dt,
    ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both
  };
}
```

Next is the needed code to keep the `cb_KPI` combo box consistent when the user selects a different tab page. Wiring up the `TabControls` `SelectedIndexChanged` event might be helpful here, the code simply loops through the `DataTable` and gathers all the different “KPI” string values and stores them into a `List<string>` then returns the completed list. This new list is then used as a `DataSource` for the `cb_KPI` combo box. Obviously, if the `DataTable` is large or there are many different tables, you may consider saving these lists of strings instead of regenerating the list every time the user selects a different tab. NOTE: The code below assumes there is a column in the table named “KPI”.

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  cb_KPI.DataSource = SetKPI_ValuesForComboBox(AllDataTables.Tables[tabControl1.SelectedIndex]);
}

private List<string> SetKPI_ValuesForComboBox(DataTable dt) {
  List<string> kpiList = new List<string> {
    "All"
  };
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
    if (!kpiList.Contains(row["KPI"].ToString()))
      kpiList.Add(row["KPI"].ToString());
  }
  return kpiList;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, @JohnG. You helped for so many times now.